# Cells(x,y).formula generates a #NAME error when referring to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying fill several cells in a sheet with a formula (Something along the lines of "=ALS($AFB$14-$AFB$13 Input!$T$2,Input!$U$2-$AFB$14,0)" (If formula, Excel is in Dutch), with Input being another sheet in the same file. It fills in the correct formula, but it gives a #Name-error. If I manually select the cell and enter the exact formula VBA generated, excel recognizes it correctly. I suppose i do something wrong in referring to other sheets, but I'm not sure what

```
'Excel is in Dutch, this would be the English formula              
            'formula =  "=IF(" & Cells(row - 1, column).Address & "-" & Cells(row - 2, column).Address & "<" & Inp.Cells(sku + 1, 20).Address(External:=True) & ";" & Inp.Cells(sku + 1, 21).Address(External:=True) & "-" & Cells(row - 1, column).Address & ";0)"

            formula = "=ALS(" & Cells(row - 1, column).Address & "-" & Cells(row - 2, column).Address & "<" & Inp.Cells(sku + 1, 20).Address(External:=True) & "," & Inp.Cells(sku + 1, 21).Address(External:=True) & "-" & Cells(row - 1, column).Address & ",0)"


      MRP.Cells(16 * sku - 1, 827 + i).formula = formula
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are using `.Formula`, it does not matter that Excel is in Dutch. It uses the English formula.

In order to use the Dutch (or the local language), use `.FormulaLocal`. To see a good example of the formulas in Excel and how they are referred to by VBA, run the following on a new Workbook:

```
Public Sub SelectAndTestMe()
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "=IF(A2=1,""OK"",""Not OK"")"
        Debug.Print .Formula
        Debug.Print .FormulaLocal
        Debug.Print .FormulaR1C1
    End With
End Sub
```

This is what you will get (if you are using German Excel) in the immediate window:

```
=IF(A2=1,"OK","Not OK")
=WENN(A2=1;"OK";"Not OK")
=IF(R[1]C=1,"OK","Not OK")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried putting the formula in English before, but I messed up commas with semicolons, resulting in an incorrect formula. I was able to fix it, thanks!